# How Orange makes decision about declaration of a meta attribute

Tags: orange

I wonder how Orange decides which attribute is declared as a string? I have few discrete attributes in Excel, which I can't use as Orange does not recognize them as discrete. Have tried export excel to csv format as well, no difference. Where in Orange I can enforce change from meta to discrete attribute?

Many thanks in advance,
Marko

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Orange supports advanced annotation with a [three-line header](http://orange-visual-programming.readthedocs.org/loading-your-data/index.html) in both CSV and Excel files. So if you have a discrete attribute that gets marked as string, you should annote it as `discrete` on the second header line, or prefix the attribute name on the first line with `D#`.

When no advanced annotation is provided, it seems Orange's heuristic treats attributes containing general strings (as opposed to numbers) as discrete only if they contain fewer than approximately $\sqrt{|data|}$ unique values.

Comment: What about data retrieved from SQL?